# How to create constant connection between Java app and Oracle DB

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, oracle, class

My question is about how JDBC connection is working and how I can set it in requested way. At beginning, my application contains two classes - DB_Connect (with standard connection-creation `try{}catch{} block`) and DB_Queries class extends DB_Connect where queries are placed.
When I'm trying to run any query, constructor from DB_Connect class is creating connection and executing query (if I understand it in correct way).
My question is: how to build these two classes to create connection to OracleDB only once when main application is starting? I hope I've explained it clearly. 
Here is DB_Connect class:

```
public class DB_Connect {

Connection conn;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;

public DB_Connect() {
    try{
    String host = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//...";
    String uName = "test";
    String uPass = "test";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,uName,uPass);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    }
    catch ( SQLException err ) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage() );
    }
}
}
```

And DB_Queries class:

```
public class DB_Queries extends DB_Connect{

private String sql;

public void get_Data(){

        try{
            sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.next();
            String smth_name = rs.getString("column_NAME");

            String p = "output: " + smth_name;
            System.out.println(p);
        }
            catch ( SQLException err ) {
                System.out.println(err.getMessage() );
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the connection object static.

```
public class DB_Connect {
    protected static Connection conn;

    public DB_Connect() {
        if (conn == null) {
            try{
                String host = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//...";
                String uName = "test";
                String uPass = "test";
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,uName,uPass);
            }
            catch ( SQLException err ) {
                System.out.println(err.getMessage() );
            }
        }
    }
}

public class DB_Queries extends DB_Connect{
   private String sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

   public void get_Data(){
        try{
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.next();
            String smth_name = rs.getString("column_NAME");

            String p = "output: " + smth_name;
            System.out.println(p);
        }
        catch ( SQLException err ) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

Generally though I wouldn't extend from the connection object but pass it via the constructor.

```
public class DB_Connect {
    private Connection conn;

    public DB_Connect() {
        try{
            String host = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//...";
            String uName = "test";
            String uPass = "test";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,uName,uPass);
        }
        catch ( SQLException err ) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    public getConnection() {
        return conn;
    }
}

public class DB_Queries {
   private String sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
   private DB_connect connect;

   public DB_Queries(DB_Connect connect) {
       this.connect= connect;
   }

   public void get_Data(){
        try{
            Statement stmt = connect.getConnection().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.next();
            String smth_name = rs.getString("column_NAME");

            String p = "output: " + smth_name;
            System.out.println(p);
        }
        catch ( SQLException err ) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create DB_Connect instance just once and reuse it (pass the instance to get_Data() method instead of extending)

```
public void get_Data(DB_Connect connection){

    try{
        sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
        rs = connection.getStatement().executeQuery(sql);
        rs.next();
        String smth_name = rs.getString("column_NAME");

        String p = "output: " + smth_name;
        System.out.println(p);
    }
        catch ( SQLException err ) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

By The way it's better to use java naming convention and have classes `DBConnect` and `DBQueries`.

It's better to create statement rather than reuse single one to avoid concurretn access problem, it's better to close resources after the end, you need to check whether the rs has data before calling `next()` etc. etc.

In general read some good tutorials about java and JDBC.